# How to find the average number of views

Tags: discussion, support, statistics

I am wondering about statistical data for questions on a specific Stack Exchange site. For example how do we determine the average number of views per question in say Mathematics SE for a certain period. Other detailed statistical questions can be explored, as in what is the probability density function of number of views, etc.

Related: [How to explore the content](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1849/how-can-we-explore-the-content-of-tex-sx)

Comment: Mods can see (but not share) stats for the site as a whole: I don't thik we can get any for individual posts

Comment: @Maesumi Maybe ask this either on main meta (there are people who like to play with SEDE) or on Mathematics Meta (high rep users there can see the number of page views for the whole site)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your best source for statistical (or raw) data is using the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) where you can search for existing queries, or build your own.

[This query](https://data.stackexchange.com/tex/query/213319/average-views-per-question-by-month) provides average views of *questions* (`PostTypeId = 1`) and average views for *questions* with a score > 0 per (post creation) month. [A modified version of this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/tex/query/1768201/average-views-per-question-by-month?FromYear=2016#graph) limits it from a user-specified year:

[image]

Comment: to clarify by the "number of views" I meant the number shown near the top of question page. For example for this question as of 7/102023, 9:11 PM CT there are 34 views. In your graph I suppose it shows the total number of views for all questions per day, or perhaps something similar. That is why it is in thousands. One more item, the standard deviation looks unusually large.